# Insert variable in specific place using sed

Tags: sed, awk, variable

i'm trying to insert variable in a file with sed

I have variable `$time` and i want insert it in index.html file in specific string(line number 53):

```
the time: <span id="$time"></span>
```

Comment: Crossposting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30685284/3776858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit your file in place, with a GNU sed, you can:

```
sed -i s/'$time'/$(date +%H:%M:%S)/ index.html
```

the trick here is [correctly quoting](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html). Notice that this will change the first `$time` in every line of your document with the time; you can limit to a specific line (say 53) with

```
sed -i 53s/'$time'/$(date +%H:%M:%S)/ index.html
```

Comment: This is *not* correctly quoted. The output of that command substitution is subject both to `$IFS` and filename generation - both of which can/will generate multiple fields. Combined with a `/` separator and the `-i` option it's... well, it's not correctly quoted.

Comment: @mikeserv I agree it's possible to break it --- but with standard shell environment is quite safe. Almost anything can be broken with `alias date=whatever` before.... but yes, strictly, you are right.

Comment: No. Aliases are only interpreted in command position and when unquoted. Your error is not a risk for affecting shell state as such - but what you are doing is calling a script editor with the unambiguous instruction that it should definitely modify and overwrite its input file, but with nothing but ambiguity as to what that input file should be - whatever it might be will depend entirely on the executing user's environment. It is not *quite safe*.